# Styling Google Fusion Tables Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have `google fusion table` file with columns `name` and `geometry`, Then i'm trying to change the map styles with different color every different name in fusion table and show in my map application (i'm using `google map api v3`) and this is my script :

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query : {
            select : 'geometry',
            from : 'xxx'
        },
        styles : [{
                where: 'name IN (Agro Industri)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#66cc66'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Bandara)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007fff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Fasilitas Pendidikan)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#cc0000'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Gardu Induk)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ff0000'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Horti & Kebun)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#66cc66'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Hutan Lindung)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007f00'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Hutan Rakyat)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007f1f'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Industri)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#c0c0c0'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Kawasan Pariwisata)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ffbf7f'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Kawasan Pemerintahan)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ff0000'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Perdagangan & Jasa)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ff00ff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Kawasan Permukiman)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ffff00'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (KKP)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#bf00ff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Kompleks Militer)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#00994c'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (KPS)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#7dd000'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Minapolitan)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007fff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Pertanian Tanaman Pangan)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#a0ffa0'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (RSUD)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#ff0000'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (RTH)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#00ff00'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Sentral Parkir)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007fff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Tahura)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#bc50f0'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Terminal Barang)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007fff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (Terminal Penumpang)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007fff'
                }
            },{
                where: 'name IN (TWA Sangeh)',
                polygonOptions : {
                    fillColor : '#007f3e'
                }
        }]
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
```

the map color has change but unfortunately all the color same, the color does not want to change in accordance with the name. 
Anybody can help my problem ? what should i do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#fusion_table_styles):

---

*Note:* Styles can only be applied to a single Fusion Tables layer per map. **You may apply up to five styles** to that layer.

---

...you've defined more than 5 styles.

To be able to have more than 5 different fillColors you may create a new column and store the desired colors in these columns. Use these columns to create a style and add the id of this style via the `styleId`-property of the FusionTablesLayerOptions